# RDLC report not loading with data

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, reportviewer, rdlc

I have developed an asp.net app which should display RDLC report which i am loading from database by calling web service. That web service is good and ok but RDLC is not being loaded with data. It shows blank RDLC instead of showing database data (Longitude, latitude)

CODE:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GPSWebservice gs = new GPSWebservice();
    List<Coordinates> lstcoords = new List<Coordinates>(gs.FetchCoordinates("hunain-8888881 ,2014-04-17 18:22, 2014-04-17 20:20:00.000"));

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Report.rdlc");
        // Customers dsCustomers = GetData("select top 20 * from customers");
        ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("Coordinates", lstcoords);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
    }
```

Web service :

```
public List<Coordinates> FetchCoordinates(String FetchParam) 
{
    List<Coordinates> Coords = new List<Coordinates>();
    Coordinates c;

    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(FetchParam))
    {
        c = new Coordinates()
        {
             Error = "No Input Provided"
        };
        Coords.Add(c);
        return Coords;
    }

    String[] parts = FetchParam.Split(',');
    sqlCom.CommandText = "FetchCoordinates";
    sqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    String IMEI = parts[0].ToString();
    DateTime DateTimeFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(parts[1]); 
    DateTime DateTimeTo = Convert.ToDateTime(parts[2]);

    sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@IMEI", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = IMEI;
    sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@DateTimeFrom", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTimeFrom.AddSeconds(-DateTimeFrom.Second);
    sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@DateTimeTo", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTimeTo.AddSeconds(-DateTimeTo.Second);
    SqlParameter sqlParam = new SqlParameter("@result", SqlDbType.Int);
    sqlCom.Parameters.Add(sqlParam);
    sqlCom.Parameters["@result"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    try
    {
        sqlCon.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader())
        {
             if (reader.HasRows)
             {
                  while (reader.Read())
                  {
                      c = new Coordinates()
                      {
                           Longitude = reader["Longitude"].ToString(),
                           Latitude = reader["Latitude"].ToString(),
                           // Error = "Times:"+"Original="+DateTimeFrom+"<br/>"+"Trimmed Time"+DateTimeFrom.AddSeconds(-DateTimeFrom.Second)
                      };
                            Coords.Add(c);

                  }
                  return Coords;
             }
             else
             {
                  c = new Coordinates()
                  {
                       Error = "No Data Found for Given Input. Could be Server Error or Try Changing IMEI or DateTime Format"
                  };
                  Coords.Add(c);
                  return Coords;
             }
        }
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {

        c = new Coordinates() 
        { 
             Error = "Something Went Wrong" 
        };
        Coords.Add(c);
        return Coords;

    }

    finally
    {
        sqlCon.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: add `this.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport();` after adding datasource. Confirm whether datasource contains records.

Comment: error: Error 1 The event 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer.ReportRefresh' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Comment: Datasource is returning LIST<> and yes list is filled with 2 columns containing 31 records but rdlc is not showing, why ?

Comment: `ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Referesh()` instead of `RefreshReport()`;

Comment: not working @HassanNisar

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I had some line (object) in my report, deleted and it showing